# estimating a particular analytic function on a bounded sector.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, interpolation

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function on $C^+=\{\Re z>0\}$, and we have the following (weaker) estimates
$$
|f(re^{i\theta},a)|\leq C (r\cos\theta)^{-n}, ~~~r>0,-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2},
$$
for some constant $C$ and $n>0$. Furthermore, on the positive real line, and for any fixed $a>0$, we have the following (stronger) estimates
$$
|f(r,a)|\leq C \frac{r}{a^{n+1}},~~~0<r\leq a,
$$
where $C$ is a constant independent with $a$. My question is can we also get the following improved estimates of $f$
$$
|f(re^{i\theta},a)|\leq C \frac{r}{a^{n+1}},~~~0<r< a,~~-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}?
$$
If not, can you give a counterexample to this?
The motivation of this question comes from estimating the Poisson semigroup $e^{-z\sqrt{-\Delta}}$ for small $|z|$ With  $\Re z>0$.To be more precise, if we let $K(z,x,y)$ be its kernel, then $K$ satisfies the estimates above with $a=|x-y|$. Although we can compute the kernel explicitly (for all $\Re z>0$ ) by using Fourier transform ($K(z,x,y)=\frac{z}{(z^2+a^2)^{n+1}}$,a=|x-y|), I think one may also obtain this by combining the kernel estimates on the positive real line (the second estimate above) with a weaker estimates on the right half plane (the first estimate above) and some analytic function theory. I don't know theorems like Hadamard's Three line lemma or its variants  would be useful here.
Thanks in advance for any comment.

Comment: If your second estimate on the positive real line holds for all $r,a>0$ with $0<r \le a$, with a uniform $C$, then you can fix $r$ and let $a \to \infty$, obtaining $f(r) = 0$ for all $r>0$.

Comment: @Geyer, sorry, the function I'm considering depends on $z$ and $a$. I have fixed it and made it clear.

Comment: I want to see a picture of this.

Comment: @Teal, the kernel of $e^{-z\sqrt{-\Delta}}$ is $K(z,x,y)=\frac{z}{(z^2+a^2)^{n+1}}$,with $a=|x-y|$.